# Can I use `Static` keyword in this situation for this purpose ?

Tags: c#, oop, collections, properties, static

```
class Position
    {
      internal static List<string> ppp = new List<string>()    `// ?`
        {  
        "Boss", 
        "Servant", 
        "Engineer", 
        };
    }

class Employee
    {
     string position;
     public string Position
    {
        get { return position; }
        private set
        {
            if (Position.ppp.Contains(value)) { position = value; }
            else { position = null; }
        }
    }
```

Hi.
Can I use `Static` keyword in this situation for this purpose ? Is it true ?
Do I have another way for using `ppp` in `class` `Employee` ?

Comment: Why are you using a `List` and not an `Enum` in this instance?

Comment: Because Position can be add items. Is it possible when I use enum ?

Comment: Sure, I am just trying to see if your approach is best. In real world for example are you using a database? Or is this a purely hypothetical question?

Comment: No, I don't use DataBase. I just learn OOP in Console.
I have class Employee and class Position.
When I create instance of Employee, I would like that to give as position only "Boss", "Servant" or "Engineer".
For example, position="Account" must be error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the use of static is fine. I have only note about thread safety:

1. If your `ppp` collection is read only, you should use array instead or mark the collection as with `readonly` keyword.
2. If you want add new items into the collection you should consider thread safety and create some synchronization construct like `System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock`  or use thread safe collection `System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<T>`

Comment: No, 'ppp' is not 'readonly'. And I dont know 'Thread' and propably I must learn.